# Redirect Middleware not working - Django

Tags: django, redirect, django-middleware

I created a simple redirect middleware

```
class RedirectMiddleware(object):
    def urlredirect(self, request):
        path = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        if "something" in path:
            URL = "http://www.someurl.com"
        else:
            URL = "http://www.otherurl.com"
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(URL)
```

But i doesnt seem to work , it doesnt does anything , and yes i added it on the settings.py, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [implement `process_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)

> Writing your own middleware is easy. Each middleware component is a
>   single Python class that defines one or more of the following methods:
>   process_request
>
> process_request(request)
>
> request is an HttpRequest object.
>
> process_request() is called on each request, before Django decides
>   which view to execute.
>
> It should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns
>   None, Django will continue processing this request, executing any
>   other process_request() middleware, then, process_view() middleware,
>   and finally, the appropriate view. If it returns an HttpResponse
>   object, Django won’t bother calling any other request, view or
>   exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it’ll apply response
>   middleware to that HttpResponse, and return the result.